# Unhandled formatExcepton

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am new to C#. I'm trying to make a calculator, but I have `FormatException` thrown:

```
private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Button button = (Button) sender;
  operationperformed = button.Text;
  result = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);  // <- here I have the exception thrown

  b = true; 
}
```

Comment: You're trying to parse a `double` from a string which doesn't represent a `double`.  For example, if the string is `"hello"` then you can't turn that into a number.  Because it's not a number.  Take a look at `double.TryParse()` for handling such situations.

Comment: it says input was not a double or number. what was the input?

Comment: try using Double.TryParse method to convert value

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a bad idea with a picture, allways add a source code please! To resolve an error try to debug your code!

Comment: this might be also because the separator. 1.3 is not the same with 1,3 and might cause an error.

Comment: Add your code to your question along with a copy of the error; it's much easier to debug than pictures and will show up in searches.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `double.TryParse` instead of `double.Parse`:

```
private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  double v;

  if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out v)) {
    // textBox1.Text doesn't contain double, e.g. "bla-bla-bla"

    //TODO:put a warning/error message here

    return; 
  }

  // textBox1.Text has a double value which is v
  operationperformed = (sender as Button).Text;
  result = v;
  b = true; 
}
```